# Search for javascript in html does not work

Tags: javascript, php, html, smarty

I want to display the search in the site header in the tpl file

```
<div  class="search-widget" >

<form method="get" action="art/search">

<input type="text"  id="artnum" value="" maxlength="40" placeholder="" > 


<button type="submit"  onclick="TDMArtSearch()">
<i class="material-icons search">&#xE8B6;</i>
 <span class="hidden-xl-down"></span>
        </button>
</form>
<div class="tclear"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function TDMArtSearch(){
    var art = $('#artnum').val();
    if(art!=''){
        art = art.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]+/g, '');
        location = '/art/search/'+art+'/';
    }
}
$('#artnum').keypress(function (e){
  if(e.which == 13){ TDMArtSearch(); return false;}
});
</script

        ></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Search does not work. If I delete `form method="get" action="art/search"`. Then search works. Only works if you click on the search button. How to apply the `form method` to start searching with the enter key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the form executes the javascript function on submit:

```
<div  class="search-widget" >

<form method="get" action="art/search" onsubmit="TDMArtSearch(); return false;">

<input type="text"  id="artnum" value="" maxlength="40" placeholder="" > 

<button type="submit"  onclick="TDMArtSearch()">
<i class="material-icons search">&#xE8B6;</i>
 <span class="hidden-xl-down"></span>
        </button>
</form>
<div class="tclear"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function TDMArtSearch(){
    var art = $('#artnum').val();
    if(art!=''){
        art = art.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]+/g, '');
        location = '/art/search/'+art+'/';
    }
}
</script

        ></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

onsubmit attribute is to execute javascript when form is submited and return false is to stop "normal" submission. There are better ways to do this by adding listeners and having cleaner HTML code, but you can look for that once you know how this works.

Comment: Thank you very much